# Upload and show image in Angular

Tags: php, mysql, angular

I hope somebody can help me on this:
For a private project I am using Angular 13 with php and mysql as the database. Now I was already able to make them all communicate with each other, which means I can upload recipe information to the database. How I fail when it comes to uploading a picture of the recipe. I know that there are 2 ways to do that: Upload the image in the database as a BLOB file or to just save the path of the image. I would prefer to 2nd way. I am able to display the image when the path is saved in the database but I cannot save it there (by letting the user select the image) and not me pasting it in manually.

I posted my code here as requested. Hope this helps. My question is still how to save the path of an image that the user selects into the database. Thanks for any adivse/help.

**recipe-new.component.html**

```
<div class="bg-success p-2 text-dark bg-opacity-10">
<br>
<div class="container">

<form #rezeptNeu="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Neues Rezept anlegen</button>
            <br><br>
            
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <h2>Allgemeine Angaben</h2><br>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><p class="fw-bold">Name</p></label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name des Rezeptes." [(ngModel)]="rezeptesammlung.name">
            </div><br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><p class="fw-bold">Kurzbeschreibung</p></label>
            <input type="text" name="textkurz" class="form-control" placeholder="Hinweise zum Rezept." [(ngModel)]="rezeptesammlung.textkurz">
            </div><br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><p class="fw-bold">Zubereitungsdauer</p></label>
            <input type="text" name="dauer" class="form-control" placeholder="Kochzeit (ohne Backen), zb 30." [(ngModel)]="rezeptesammlung.dauer">
            </div><br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><p class="fw-bold">Schwierigkeitsgrad</p></label>
                <select class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" name="schwierigkeitsgrad" [(ngModel)]="rezeptesammlung.schwierigkeitsgrad">
                    <option selected>Bitte auswählen...</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/schwierigkeit/hauben1.png">leicht</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/schwierigkeit/hauben2.png">mittel</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/schwierigkeit/hauben3.png">schwer</option>
                </select>
            </div><br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><p class="fw-bold">Kategorie</p></label>
                <select class="form-select" name="category" [(ngModel)]="rezeptesammlung.category">
                    <option selected>Bitte auswählen...</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/birnenkuchen.jpg">Frühstück</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/gurkensalat.jpg">Mittagessen</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/gurkensalat.jpg">Abendessen</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/gurkensalat.jpg">Nachspeise</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/gurkensalat.jpg">Sonstiges</option>
                </select>
             </div><br>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label><p class="fw-bold">Rating</p></label>
                <select class="form-select" name="rating" [(ngModel)]="rezeptesammlung.rating">
                    <option selected>Bitte auswählen...</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/rating/stern_1.png">1 Stern</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/rating/stern_2.png">2 Sterne</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/rating/stern_3.png">3 Sterne</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/rating/stern_4.png">4 Sterne</option>
                    <option value="http://localhost/kochen/uploads/rating/stern_5.png">5 Sterne</option>
                </select>
             </div><br>

           <div class="form-group">
                <label><p class="fw-bold">Image</p></label>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rezeptesammlung.image">
            </div><br>
            
    </div>

    <!--für Abstand-->
    <div class="col-1">
        </div>

    <div class="col-7">
        <h2>Zubereitungsschritte und Zutaten</h2><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br>  
                    <label><p class="fw-bold">Schritt 1</p></label><br>
                <textarea name="zubereitung_1" class="form-control" rows="5" [(ngModel)]="rezeptesammlung.zubereitung_1"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br>
                    <label><p class="fw-bold">Schritt 2</p></label><br>
                <textarea name="zubereitung_2" class="form-control" rows="5" [(ngModel)]="rezeptesammlung.zubereitung_2"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br>
                    <label><p class="fw-bold">Schritt 3</p></label><br>
                <textarea name="zubereitung_3" class="form-control" rows="5" [(ngModel)]="rezeptesammlung.zubereitung_3"></textarea>
                </div><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <!--für Abstand-->
        <div class="col-1"> </div>

        <div class="col-8">
           <!-- <h2>Zutaten</h2><br>-->
            <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <br>
                <label><p class="fw-bold">Zutaten</p></label><br>
            <textarea name="zutaten" class="form-control" rows="5" [(ngModel)]="rezeptesammlung.zutaten"></textarea>
            </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
       </div>

    </div>
   
</form>

</div>
```

**Rezept-neu.component.html**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RezepteService } from '../rezepte.service';
import { RezepteSammlung } from '../rezepte-sammlung';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rezept-neu',
  templateUrl: './rezept-neu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rezept-neu.component.css']
})
export class RezeptNeuComponent {

  rezeptesammlung = new RezepteSammlung('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');

  constructor(private Rezept: RezepteService) { }

  onSubmit() {
   this.Rezept.make(this.rezeptesammlung).subscribe(rezepte => console.log('Erfolgreich gepspeichert', rezepte));

  }

}
```

**recipe.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RezepteSammlung } from './rezepte-sammlung';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RezepteService {
  //REST-API
  private api1 = 'http://localhost/kochen/angular1.php';
  private api2 = 'http://localhost/kochen/angular2.php';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //get-Methode, damit werden die Daten vom Server ausgelesen
  loadRezepte(): Observable<RezepteSammlung[]> {
    return this.http.get<RezepteSammlung[]>(this.api1);
  }
  //Damit sendet man die Daten zum Server.
  make(rezepte: RezepteSammlung) {
    console.log(rezepte);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.api2, rezepte);
  }

}
```

**php**

```
<?php
$con = new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "", "kochen");

if ($con->connect_error) {
    echo "Fehler bei der Verbindung: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
    }

if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")){
echo "Fehler bei utf8" . $con->error;
}

$essen = [];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rezepte";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$nr = 0; //damit er weiterzählt
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

{
    $essen[$nr]['rezeptid'] = $row['rezeptid'];
    $essen[$nr]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $essen[$nr]['textkurz'] = $row['textkurz'];
    $essen[$nr]['dauer'] = $row['dauer'];
    $essen[$nr]['schwierigkeitsgrad'] = $row['schwierigkeitsgrad'];
    $essen[$nr]['speicherung'] = $row['speicherung'];
    $essen[$nr]['category'] = $row['category'];
    $essen[$nr]['zubereitung_1'] = $row['zubereitung_1'];
    $essen[$nr]['zubereitung_2'] = $row['zubereitung_2'];
    $essen[$nr]['zubereitung_3'] = $row['zubereitung_3'];
    $essen[$nr]['rating'] = $row['rating'];
    $essen[$nr]['zutaten'] = $row['zutaten'];
    $essen[$nr]['image'] = $row['image'];
    $nr++;
}


echo json_encode($essen);
?>
```

Here is the  api2 - php file:

```
<?php

$connect = new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "", "kochen");

//Get the data
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

//Extract the data
$request = json_decode($postdata);

//Entfernung von Zeichen, die beim SQL-Befehl problematisch sein könnten
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, ($request->name));
$textkurz = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, ($request->textkurz));
$dauer = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, ($request->dauer));
$schwierigkeitsgrad = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, ($request->schwierigkeitsgrad));
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, ($request->category));
$zubereitung_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, ($request->zubereitung_1));
$zubereitung_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, ($request->zubereitung_2));
$zubereitung_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, ($request->zubereitung_3));
$rating = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, ($request->rating));
$zutaten = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, ($request->zutaten));
$image = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, ($request->image));

$sql = "INSERT INTO rezepte (name, textkurz, dauer, schwierigkeitsgrad, category, zubereitung_1, zubereitung_2, zubereitung_3, rating, zutaten, image)
VALUES ('{$name}', '{$textkurz}', '{$dauer}', '{$schwierigkeitsgrad}', '{$category}', '{$zubereitung_1}', '{$zubereitung_2}', '{$zubereitung_3}', '{$rating}', '{$zutaten}', '{$image}');";

mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

?>
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: "C:\\fakepath\\besteck.jpg" besteck.jpg is the image file I select.

Comment: Can you post the details / code that does not work? Including an error? The current details are not sufficient to provide an answer

Comment: Hello, I added my current code above.

Comment: In ```make(rezepte: RezepteSammlung)``` you have a console.log(). What is the result of this log? And can you share the code for storing data (api2)? Do you get an error when calling api2? Or does it just not store the filename? When using backslashes you should take care that they are properly encoded because they are also considered as special characters.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. The result of this code is that in the console I get the message "Erfolgreich gespeichert" which means "Saved successfully" in English. I will put the code for api2 online. There is no error code: In my database the path  C:\fakepath\Bild1.bmp is stored under image.

Comment: I now understand your issue, sorry it took some time. You only get the filename, not the complete path to your file. This is a browser limitation, as they don't want you to access the local file system.

Comment: Thanks. Isn’t there any suggestion what I can do?

Comment: Upload the file

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for a local experiment then you could try store the images in the assets folder of your angular project and then reference them in your component. In that way you can still select them in your frontend, however this will not allow you to add images after you have deployed your app on a server. Then the only way is to upload images and store them (either in a database or blob storage or server folder where you have access)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. I managed to upload them to the serve and to save the path in the database. Angular's reavtive forms helped me here.